# How to extract values from XML in PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, plpgsql

I have input varchar parameter in my PostgreSQL function:

```xml
<File xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" FILE_CREATE="2020-02-17T17:43:55" FILE_NAME="test02.txt"></File>
```

How to extract 'test02.txt' value from this XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [xpath()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) for that:

```
select (xpath('/File/@FILE_NAME', parameter::xml))[1]::text
```

`xpath()` returns an array of all matches and the `[1]` picks the first element from that array.

or inside PL/pgSQL:

```
the_variable := (xpath('/File/@FILE_NAME', parameter::xml))[1]::text;
```

---

(Obviously you have to replace `the_variable` and `parameter` with the names that you use)

Comment: Hello! Can you help me again? I have mor ecomplex xml in input parameter now: <File xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" FILE_CREATE="2020-02-17T17:43:55" FILE_NAME="test02.txt"><PPK><InfoP result="123" /></PPK></File> How can i get 'result' value?